# Downloading a zip archive from Express endpoint

Tags: node.js, express, download, archive

I have a simple issue, but it's been driving me crazy for the past 2 days.
I have an `archive.zip` file in my node/express app which I'm trying to send via a response.
My code is pretty simple, I have an endpoint `/download` whos only job is to do `response.download("archive.zip")`.

However, upon downloading the file (by accessing the URL through a browser), the .zip archive is downloaded, but the files in the archive are corrupted, and I get the error `Unexpected end of archive`.

The actual file is a good, non-corrupted archive. I can access it on the windows filesystem without any problems. It's just when it gets transferred it gets corrupted.

I have tried setting various response headers, among which:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment
Content-Type: application/zip, application/content-stream
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Nothing has worked up to this point. I have searched far and wide on google / reddit / stackoverflow and haven't come up with a solution so far.

Thank you for any or all responses.

NOTE: I'm using Express Router (require('express').Router())

NOTE2: The simple zip I'm trying to download - http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=06192736420392118369

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  I tried `const app=require('express')();app.get('/download',(req,res)=>res.download('notes.zip'));app.listen(3333,()=>{});` and navigated a browser to `localhost:3333/download` and the file was downloaded fine.  Please try reducing your problem down to the minimal code somebody can run, WITH an example zip file which is not working, and then add that to your question.

Comment: The only thing I forgot to mention is that I'm using ('express').Router(). 
That's the only difference between your example and mine. The code is really simple, I have an endpoint specifically for this download, the endpoint code is `response.download("archive.zip")` without anything else.
I have uploaded the simple zip file I'm trying to download - http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=06192736420392118369

Comment: After a bit of searching I realised if I create a simple application with only one endpoint, it works. However, in my real-life app, it doesn't. I guess I'm gonna have to find out the cause, I suspect some middleware is interfering with the download.

Comment: Please do list the middleware you are using, and if you can the setup.  If you can gradually add middleware to your simple example to narrow down what is causeing the problem, then this could make the question really useful for others too who hit the problem.

Comment: so, tried including using the express router plus your zip file: `const express=require('express'),route=express.Router().get('/download',(_,res)=>res.download('nothing.zip'));express().use('/v2',route).listen(3334,()=>{});`.  Also works just fine at `http://localhost:3334/v2/download`.

Comment: My middleware is just:

app.use(cors())

app.use(express.static('build'))

app.use(bodyParser.json())

Disabling these 3 middleware didn't help me solve the corruption issue.
I'm going to have to look deeper, because I'm not sure WHAT else could be causing this except the middleware.

Again, on my "demo app" (simple app with nothing installed except express, with a single route set up) this works fine without any problems.

Once I find a solution I'll post it here as well. Wish me luck

Comment: Absolutely! Bugs like this are often not where you expect them to be.  Any code you can share we can look at, however if you are unable to then all I can do is offer good (bug) hunting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from bad async patterns and chaining. The operations were not executing in the correct order, thus my archive was being sent before it was finalized.